Cartopy non-PlateCarree projections result in empty plot
I am trying to plot some climate data on a map of a part of Scandinavia. In the codes below I left out the non-relevant parts, focusing on the parts relying on the transform and projection.
Using PlateCarree() as both transform and projection keywords works, but in that projection the map is skewed:
dataset_LU = Dataset('data.nc', 'r')
LU = dataset_LU.variables['LU_INDEX'][0,:,:]
lats = dataset_LU.variables['XLAT_M'][0,:,:]
lons = dataset_LU.variables['XLONG_M'][0,:,:]

projection = crs.PlateCarree()
transform = crs.PlateCarree()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncolumns,
                        subplot_kw = {'projection': projection},
                        figsize = (11,8.5))

cs = axs.contourf(lons, lats, LU, 60, transform=transform, 
                  levels=levels, cmap=cmap2, extend='both')
axs.set_extent(bbox, projection)


When using Mercator() as both transform and projection, the map shows but without the black lines, with wrong ocean colour and still on the skewed projection:
dataset_LU = Dataset('data.nc', 'r')
LU = dataset_LU.variables['LU_INDEX'][0,:,:]
lats = dataset_LU.variables['XLAT_M'][0,:,:]
lons = dataset_LU.variables['XLONG_M'][0,:,:]

projection = crs.Mercator()
transform = crs.Mercator()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncolumns,
                        subplot_kw = {'projection': projection},
                        figsize = (11,8.5))

cs = axs.contourf(lons, lats, LU, 60, transform=transform, 
                  levels=levels, cmap=cmap2, extend='both')
axs.set_extent(bbox, projection)


When using Mercator() as projection and PlateCarree() as transform the code takes a long time and then shows an empty plot:
dataset_LU = Dataset('data.nc', 'r')
LU = dataset_LU.variables['LU_INDEX'][0,:,:]
lats = dataset_LU.variables['XLAT_M'][0,:,:]
lons = dataset_LU.variables['XLONG_M'][0,:,:]

projection = crs.Mercator()
transform = crs.PlateCarree()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncolumns,
                        subplot_kw = {'projection': projection},
                        figsize = (11,8.5))

cs = axs.contourf(lons, lats, LU, 60, transform=transform, 
                  levels=levels, cmap=cmap2, extend='both')
axs.set_extent(bbox, projection)


What am I misunderstanding here? How can I solve the issue and display my data on the Mercator (or any other non-PlateCarree) projection?

What do you get if you do scatter instead of contourf?

Then I get these errors: "TypeError: len() of unsized object" and "ValueError: 'c' argument has 1 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 399000." If I try pcolormesh in stead of contourf (following these examples: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html), then I get the same results as above, although the colours in the PlateCarree PlateCarree projections have shifted.

Turns out the fix was really easy. The only problem with the last plot was that projection was also specified in axs.set_extent(bbox, projection). This messed up the plotting and resulted in a white field. Changing this to axs.set_extent(bbox) fixed the issue!
Transforming the data to fit the projection is the reason it takes so long to load.

